# newenvironment/newcommand for existing environment in LaTeX-Beamer

Tags: listings, environments

I would like to have [the solution of highlighting a line in `listings`-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304315/highlighting-a-chunk-of-code-within-a-lstlisting/1313704#1313704)  as a command or environment. To bad I cannot get it working. I tried:

- a simple `newenvironment`: compile errors
- `\newcommand`: also compile errors
- the [`environ`-package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872951/wrap-latex-command-in-environment/1877976#1877976), see below

  ```
  \NewEnviron{listingh}{
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{yellow}]
    \BODY
    \end{lstlisting}
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  }
  ```

Also, same kind of errors. `missing {`, `missing number, threaded a zero` etc.

I try to use it with the `beamer`-package and `pdflatex`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `lstlisting` environment is like all verbatim environments special and doesn't work (well) inside another environments. You need to use `\lstnewenvironment` as described in the `listings` manual in section 4.16 *Environments*, p.40:

```
\lstnewenvironment
    {<name>}[<number>][<opt. default arg.>]
    {<starting code>}
    {<ending code>}
```

Applied to your code:

```
\lstnewenvironment{listingh}[1][]{%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},#1}%
}{%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}
```

Note the `%` at the end of lines to avoid spurious spaces.

You need to use the `fragile` option of the `frame` environment (or command) if you use `listings` or any other verbatim code.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Martin's answer, you need to take special care within the beamer class, because that class also drastically alters LaTeX's expansion habits.  See section 2.6 of the beamer manual.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{listingh}[1][]{%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
    \lstset{backgroundcolor=\color{yellow},#1}%
}{%
    \vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}


\begin{document}

\defverbatim[colored]\mycode{%
\begin{listingh}[emph={PRINT,GOTO},emphstyle={\color{blue}}]
10 PRINT "HELLO, WORLD!"
20 GOTO 10
\end{listingh} }


\begin{frame}{BASIC}
\mycode
\end{frame}

% or
\begin{frame}[fragile]{C++}
\begin{listingh}[emph={cout,for},emphstyle={\color{blue}}]
for (;;) {
    cout << "Hello, world!";
}
\end{listingh}

\end{document}
```

This looks bad but keep in mind you can redefine `\mycode` over and over again before each frame.

Comment: Why not just use the `fragile` option for the frame? It works fine in my test.

Comment: Good point, I've edited.  Is there a situation where `fragile` doesn't work?  Or is this workaround in the manual vestigial?

Comment: The section 2.6 referenced by you mentions a couple of times: "[...] either add the `fragile`
option to the frame or use the `\defverbatim` command". So it seems that both are equal. For `listings` it says "tread it like a `verbatim` environment` and then "When using `\defverbatim` that contains a colored `lstlisting`, use the colored option of
`\defverbatim`". It doesn't explicitly state that `fragile` can or cannot be used, just tells you that `colored` is required for colors.